# How to solve Error C2039?

Tags: c++, tree

I'm trying to get count repeated instances of strings inserted into a tree. I'm modifying the code straight out of my textbook, and it seems rather convoluted to me, but I don't know much. The countDupes method in line 141 causes a C2039 error, stating that countdupes is not a member of AvlNode. If someone would be so kind as to tell me what to fix or point me in the direction, I would love you for ever. Segment below looks really long, but it's mostly comments. Thanks in advance.

```
#ifndef AVL_TREE_H
#define AVL_TREE_H
#include "except.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;


template <typename Comparable>
class AvlTree
{
public:
int wordCount = 0;
int repeatedWordCount = 1;

AvlTree() : root{ nullptr }
{ }

AvlTree(const AvlTree & rhs) : root{ nullptr }
{
    root = clone(rhs.root);
}

AvlTree(AvlTree && rhs) : root{ rhs.root }
{
    rhs.root = nullptr;
}

~AvlTree()
{
    makeEmpty();
}


/**
* Test if the tree is logically empty.
* Return true if empty, false otherwise.
*/
bool isEmpty() const
{
    return root == nullptr;
}

/**
* Print the tree contents in sorted order.
*/
void printTree() const
{
    if (isEmpty())
        cout << "Empty tree" << endl;
    else
        printTree(root) ;
    cout << endl << "Total Words: " << wordCount << "\t" << endl;;
}

/**
* Make the tree logically empty.
*/
void makeEmpty()
{
    makeEmpty(root);
}

/**
* Insert x into the tree, count duplicates
*/
void insert(const Comparable & x)
{
    insert(x, root);
    wordCount++;
    countDupes();
}

/**
* Insert x into the tree
*/
void insert(Comparable && x)
{

    insert(std::move(x), root);
    wordCount++;
    countDupes();
}

void countDupes()
{
    repeatedWordCount = repeatedWordCount + 1;
}


int getWordCount()
{
    return wordCount;
}
private:
struct AvlNode
{
    Comparable element;
    AvlNode   *left;
    AvlNode   *right;
    int       height;

    AvlNode(const Comparable & ele, AvlNode *lt, AvlNode *rt, int h = 0)
        : element{ ele }, left{ lt }, right{ rt }, height{ h } { }

    AvlNode(Comparable && ele, AvlNode *lt, AvlNode *rt, int h = 0)
        : element{ std::move(ele) }, left{ lt }, right{ rt }, height{ h } { }
};

AvlNode *root;


/**
* Internal method to insert into a subtree.
* x is the item to insert.
* t is the node that roots the subtree.
* Set the new root of the subtree.
*/
void insert(const Comparable & x, AvlNode * & t)
{
    if (t == nullptr)
        t = new AvlNode{ x, nullptr, nullptr };
    else if (x < t->element)
        insert(x, t->left);
    else if (t->element < x)
        insert(x, t->right);
    else if (t->element == x)
        t->countDupes();

    balance(t);
}

/**
* Internal method to insert into a subtree.
* x is the item to insert.
* t is the node that roots the subtree.
* Set the new root of the subtree.
*/
void insert(Comparable && x, AvlNode * & t)
{
    if (t == nullptr)
        t = new AvlNode{ std::move(x), nullptr, nullptr };
    else if (x < t->element)
        insert(std::move(x), t->left);
    else if (t->element < x)
        insert(std::move(x), t->right);
    else if (t->element == x)
        t->countDupes();

    balance(t);
}

static const int ALLOWED_IMBALANCE = 1;

// Assume t is balanced or within one of being balanced
void balance(AvlNode * & t)
{
    if (t == nullptr)
        return;

    if (height(t->left) - height(t->right) > ALLOWED_IMBALANCE)
    if (height(t->left->left) >= height(t->left->right))
        rotateWithLeftChild(t);
    else
        doubleWithLeftChild(t);
    else
    if (height(t->right) - height(t->left) > ALLOWED_IMBALANCE)
    if (height(t->right->right) >= height(t->right->left))
        rotateWithRightChild(t);
    else
        doubleWithRightChild(t);

    t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right)) + 1;
}

/**
* Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree t.
* Return node containing the smallest item.
*/
AvlNode * findMin(AvlNode *t) const
{
    if (t == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if (t->left == nullptr)
        return t;
    return findMin(t->left);
}

/**
* Internal method to find the largest item in a subtree t.
* Return node containing the largest item.
*/
AvlNode * findMax(AvlNode *t) const
{
    if (t != nullptr)
    while (t->right != nullptr)
        t = t->right;
    return t;
}


/**
* Internal method to test if an item is in a subtree.
* x is item to search for.
* t is the node that roots the tree.
*/
bool contains(const Comparable & x, AvlNode *t) const
{
    if (t == nullptr)
        return false;
    else if (x < t->element)
        return contains(x, t->left);
    else if (t->element < x)
        return contains(x, t->right);
    else
        return true;    // Match
}
/****** NONRECURSIVE VERSION*************************
bool contains( const Comparable & x, AvlNode *t ) const
{
while( t != nullptr )
if( x < t->element )
t = t->left;
else if( t->element < x )
t = t->right;
else
return true;    // Match

return false;   // No match
}
*****************************************************/

/**
* Internal method to make subtree empty.
*/
void makeEmpty(AvlNode * & t)
{
    if (t != nullptr)
    {
        makeEmpty(t->left);
        makeEmpty(t->right);
        delete t;
    }
    t = nullptr;
}

/**
* Internal method to print a subtree rooted at t in sorted order.
*/
void printTree(AvlNode *t) const
{
    if (t != nullptr)
    {
        printTree(t->left);
        cout << t->element << "\t \t \t " << repeatedWordCount << endl;
        printTree(t->right);
    }
}

// Avl manipulations
/**
* Return the height of node t or -1 if nullptr.
*/
int height(AvlNode *t) const
{
    return t == nullptr ? -1 : t->height;
}

int max(int lhs, int rhs) const
{
    return lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs;
}

/**
* Rotate binary tree node with left child.
* For AVL trees, this is a single rotation for case 1.
* Update heights, then set new root.
*/
void rotateWithLeftChild(AvlNode * & k2)
{
    AvlNode *k1 = k2->left;
    k2->left = k1->right;
    k1->right = k2;
    k2->height = max(height(k2->left), height(k2->right)) + 1;
    k1->height = max(height(k1->left), k2->height) + 1;
    k2 = k1;
}

/**
* Rotate binary tree node with right child.
* For AVL trees, this is a single rotation for case 4.
* Update heights, then set new root.
*/
void rotateWithRightChild(AvlNode * & k1)
{
    AvlNode *k2 = k1->right;
    k1->right = k2->left;
    k2->left = k1;
    k1->height = max(height(k1->left), height(k1->right)) + 1;
    k2->height = max(height(k2->right), k1->height) + 1;
    k1 = k2;
}

/**
* Double rotate binary tree node: first left child.
* with its right child; then node k3 with new left child.
* For AVL trees, this is a double rotation for case 2.
* Update heights, then set new root.
*/
void doubleWithLeftChild(AvlNode * & k3)
{
    rotateWithRightChild(k3->left);
    rotateWithLeftChild(k3);
}

/**
* Double rotate binary tree node: first right child.
* with its left child; then node k1 with new right child.
* For AVL trees, this is a double rotation for case 3.
* Update heights, then set new root.
*/
void doubleWithRightChild(AvlNode * & k1)
{
    rotateWithLeftChild(k1->right);
    rotateWithRightChild(k1);
}
};

#endif
```

Comment: why you call t->countDupes() in the two insert functions. t is sturct and the countDupes() is not its member

Comment: It would be helpful if you could pull out a snippet of what line 141 is. I for one do not feel like counting

Comment: Well countDupes is not a member of AvlNode, it's a member of AvlTree. You are trying t->countDupes() when t is a pointer to an AvlNode.

Comment: I'm really confused as to how one would count individual repetitions. For example, if the three strings being inserted into the tree were "tree" "node" and "tree", how would I get it to tell me that there are two instances of "tree" and one of "node"?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you're trying to call `countDupes` on a node, which has no such member. Although you didn't point out which lines of the large example were causing this, I'm assuming it's the following lines in the two `insert` functions:

```
t->countDupes();
```

You want to call it on a tree; presumably that tree should be the one you're calling `insert` on, so remove `t->` (or replace it with `this->`) to call it on the tree instead.

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm not thinking clearly. Fixed that, now it's printing out a constant number for all words included, and that number is greater than the total words in the text file that it is reading from. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2896852: Step through your test program in a debugger to see where that number is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `countDupes()` is actually a member of `AvlTree`, and you are trying to invoke it through a pointer to an `AvlNode`.

Replace this:

```
t->countDupes();
```

With this:

```
this->countDupes();
```